# React application video hangs, browser shows many "pending" streams

Tags: reactjs, mjpeg

I have a complex application built using react-redux framwework. Among many other things, it needs to serve MJPEG image streams. The app has multiple tabs (react-tabs, to be precise), and many streams are only visible on some. When the user operates the app fast enough, the video streaming hangs, with multiple streams showing in the browser inspection window as "pending". Many of these pending streams are no longer visible.

Serving the streams is currently implemented with the simple img tag within react `render` method:

```
<img src='http://a.b.file.jpg/>
```

I tried to use onLoad and onError callbacks, but if the stream is shown as "pending" in the browser (developer tools window), none of these is called. Is it a way to detect the "pending" state and force - reload the image or in the worst case at least trigger the complete reload of the application?

I also observed (from the server logs) that some streams are requested multiple times, even if there is only one image on the page, and it has been asked to be displayed only once. This worsens the situation significantly. What can be done to improve reliability of the image streaming within react app?

Answer (score 0):

The browser has the number of connections per server limit and would not show too many videos that stream from the same server. This may also be true if some videos are no longer visible but the application or browser failed to realize for some reason and the connection have stayed open. Videos that would be over the limit become "pending", further worsening the problem.

Mundane but working solution was to reload the page from JavaScript in cases where these stalls are likely.